# How to use splice method to solve my problem correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

I am displaying rotating images.

```
var pics= [
    "images/img1.jpg",
    "images/img2.jpg",
    "images/img3.jpg",
];
```

And would want it to stop `onClick`.

```
function StopRotate(interval, imgIndex) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var permanentImage = picture[imgIndex].src;
    picture[imgIndex].src = permanentImage;
    pics.splice(pics.indexOf(picture[imgIndex].src), 1);
}
```

Here's how I rotate the images (this block has three occurrences for three image containers):

```
interval0 = setInterval(function () {
    if(pics.length != 1) {
        picture[0].src = pics[count];
        count++;
        if (count == pics.length) count = 0;
    }
    else picture[0].src = pics[0];
}, 10);
```

But the image occurs yet again to other frames even if the path has been already removed from the array.  I tried this using 12 images.  Some times when I run it, the src turns out to be undefined.

Also if I click the images unordered, the images from other frames becomes blank. In this sample, I have three images, if I clicked on the third container, the first container becomes blank, how does that affect other frames when the interval functions are separate.  There's no problem however when clicking it in order.  Note I have changed the sequence where I put the if condition inside setInterval.

Comment: can u show the demo of ur file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.src` property will return a fully qualified pathname which will never be found in your array of partial path names when you try to look for it with `.indexOf()`.

You can use `.getAttribute("src")` to get what is actually in the HTML and that should then match what you have in your array.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3H8XF/

Comment: my bad, yup you're right full path is never found in my array.  Also if I click the images unordered, the images from other frames becomes blank.